# what do mean "renewal domain" for free service?

Tags: domains, free

sorry for bad english.
if renewing cz.cc free domain is free then what do mean renewing domain after two years?
(why we should renew for free service when it is free?)

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I can make out from your question:

1) They might have given you free domain for only 2 years and after two years they expect you to pay fees to continue.

OR

2) They want to make sure you are using your free domain (it is active and not just lying there). Hence maybe they want you to manually "renew" even if they don't want any fee.

(They => the company that gave you free domain).

Comment: And don't forget to check the terms and conditions ;)

Comment: cz.cc site says renew is absolutely free. two years for what?

Comment: can you post the link where they talk about renewal? I can't find it.

Comment: http://www.nic.cz.cc/tos.php   DOMAIN ASSIGNMENT POLICY  5th paragraph . it says: All free CZCC domain names will stay for free for lifetime. CZCC will never start to charge a fee for free domain names for registration or for renewals.

Comment: In that case you'll need to renew. Many companies will auto-renew domains, but czcc probably does not.